# How Hibernate session.getTransaction().commit() knows there are private field changes without calling getter?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

If I change firstName value by calling setFirstName(String newFirstName) and then commit data with session.getTransaction().commit(), everything works fine, but how Hibernate knows new Student first name without calling getFirstName() in Student class ?

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            Student student = session.get(Student.class, 1);
            student.setFirstName("Michael");
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
```

Student class getter:

```
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
    System.out.println("Getting first name: "+firstName); //never printed
    return firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in `Student` entity the `@Id` annotation is placed on the field and not on the getter. Smth like:

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

In this case, Hibernate uses the "field-based access type", i.e. it reads or writes all fields of the entity directly (via reflection). So, while performing dirty check, it just reads the values of `Student` fields (`firstName` too) without using their getters.

You can change this behavior to "property-based" access type by placing `@Id` on the corresponding getter of "id" field.

Or you can use [@AttributeAccessor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/AttributeAccessor.html) (or its JPA's equivalent - [@Access](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Access.html)) to override this behavior.

There are pros and cons of these 2 access types. Read more about it [in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/access.html).